# In a Angular Project, how can I change the style based on the route?

Tags: angular, routes, sass

In a Angular Project, how can I change the style based on the route?
I have a navbar and I want it to change depending on what route it is.
Like, depending on what page I am, the navbar will look different.

I don't know how to start with this. A help will be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to `Router` from `@angular/router` in your navbar component like this:

```
export class YourComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private routeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.routeSubscription = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('route: ' + router.url);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Then instead of `console.log(router.url)` you can store that value into property of your component and use it in HTML template with `[ngClass]` like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{ 
        'class1': myRoute == '/route1', 
        'class2': myRoute == '/route2'
     }"
>Navbar</div>
```

Then add different styles to each class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some data to your routes to make them configurable and keep the navbar component unaware about the route paths. For example:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {
     path: 'page1',
     component: Page1Component,
     data: {
        navbar: 'dark'
      }
  },
  {
     path: 'page2',
     component: Page2Component,
     data: {
        navbar: 'transparent'
      }
  }
];
```

Then in your navbar component:

```
 class NavbarComponent {
     constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

     ngOnInit() {
        this.navbarStyle$ = this.route
          .data
          .pipe(map((data) => data.navbar));
     }
  }
```

}

And finally the navbar template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="navbarStyle$ | async as navbarStyle">
    <div class="navbar" [class.navbar-dark]="navbarStyle === 'dark'". 
        [class.navbar-transparent]="navbarStyle === 'transparent'">
        ...
    </div>
<ng-container>
```